# Insert array data to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

How can I insert array data from web page to mysql table using below code.
actually i want to import data from xls/csv/xml files to web page then want to insert to mysql table. like the tutorial from this link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-phpexcel/.

```html
    <html>
<body>
These records have been added to the database:
<table>
<tr>
<th>First</th>
<th>Middle</th>
<th>Last</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach( $data as $row ) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo( $row['first'] ); ?></td><
<td><?php echo( $row['middle'] ); ?></td><
<td><?php echo( $row['last'] ); ?></td><
<td><?php echo( $row['email'] ); ?></td><
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
Click <a href="list.php">here</a> for the entire table.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($row));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($insData));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table`($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach( $data as $row ) { 
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
}
?>
```

Comment: you want to store whole array in a single colum , right ?

Comment: he wants to fetch data from xls and save in database table.. seems to be different column in table for sure..

Comment: Column Name is Same in database as per excel column. As i am new to PHP, can you please show me where i need to place your code to store information into mysql table.

Comment: refer w3schools link on how to insert data into database since your new you will get an better idea http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: you are storing data to single colum or multiple colums ??

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach( $data as $row ) { 
$sql= "INSERT INTO table_name (`first`, `middle`, `last`,`email`)VALUES (".$row['first'].", ".$row['middle'].", ".$row['last'].",".$row['email'].")";
}
$query = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```